# Convert random sequence of characters to JSON

Tags: python, json, regex, string

I have a long list (or whatever you may call it) of subsequent strings in this format:

**"(str10, str20, str30), (str11, str21, str31), (str12, str22, str32), ..."**

All strings within brackets are in single quotes.

I'd like to convert the whole string to JSON, extract all strings within brackets as values and assign a certain key to them. Since I only know JS and Python (and I'm obviously not a pro), I tried to do it with regular expressions. The problem is, however, *that JS doesn't recognize the above list (or whatever you may call it) as a string*. Manually adding escape characters is impracticable since the list is to long. So, I can't figure out how to do it...

Is there a general approach (maybe a suited language, a certain library or sth.) to search for such patterns and extract them ? Thanks!

**My Attempt**

```
/([A-Z]{2})',\s'(.+)',\s'(.+)/g
```

**Example List**

```
"""
('AD', 'Andorra', 'Hola'),
('AE', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Marhaba'),
('AF', 'Afghanistan', 'Senga yai'),
('AG', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Hello'),
('AI', 'Anguilla', 'Hello'),
('AL', 'Albania', 'Tungjatjeta'), ...
"""
```

**Expected Output**

```
[{"key1": "AD", "key2": "Andorra", "key3": "Hola"},
  {"key1": "AE", "key2": "United Arab Emirates", "key3": "Marhaba"},
  {"key1": "AF", "key2": "Afghanistan", "key3": "Senga yai"},
  {"key1": "AG", "key2": "Antigua and Barbuda", "key3": "Hello"},
  {"key1": "AI", "key2": "Anguilla", "key3": "Hello"},
  {"key1": "AL", "key2": "Albania", "key3": "Tungjatjeta"}, ...
]
```

Comment: can you split by "), (" and you'll get an array of combined string "str10, str20, str30". Further you can split it again with "," to have str10, str20, and str30 separately. Assuming the pattern is the same throughout the document

Comment: Expected result.

Comment: @S.Jovan The expected result should look sth. like this:
[
  { "key1": str10, "key2": str20, "key3": str30 },
  { "key1": str11, "key2": str21, "key3": str31 },
  { "key1": str12, "key2": str22, "key3": str32 },
  ...
]

Comment: @KendrickKesley the document is too long to split it manually. Is there a way to automate this ?

Comment: @S.Jovan In js syntax this regex `/([A-Z]{2})',\s'(.+)',\s'(.+)/g` finds all occurrences and groups them appropriately. One example would be _('VA', 'Holy See (Vatican City State)', 'Buon giorno')_

Comment: You forgot to add `/([A-Z]{2})',\s'(.+)',\s'(.+)/g` with re.findall

Comment: Yes, I figured this pattern doesn't quite fit the example. But yours works like a charm...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.sub()` and regex.

**Regex**: [`\(\s*'([^']+)'[^']+'([^']+)'[^']+'([^']+)'\s*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/leMjrn/2)

Substitution: `{"key1": "\1", "key2": "\2", "key3": "\3"}`

**Python code**:

```
r = r"\(\s*'([^']+)'[^']+'([^']+)'[^']+'([^']+)'\s*\)"
sub = r'{"key1": "\1", "key2": "\2", "key3": "\3"}'

json = "[%s]" % re.sub(r, sub, text)
```

Output:

```
[{"key1": "str10", "key2": "str20", "key3": "str30"}, {"key1": "str11", "key2": "str21", "key3": "str31"}, {"key1": "str11", "key2": "str21", "key3": "str31"}]
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/ZBvDE8)